# NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW for specific template (phtml) file?

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml

I am using a custom template file to display a form. This has `content="INDEX,FOLLOW"` set as this is the Magento standard. Is there a way to reset that to NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW for that single phtml file?

**Magento 1.9.x**

Thanks for helping

Comment: Can you please give some feedback?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using separate page and it can be done using controller file as well.

```
<?php
class Vendor_Extension_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
        public function YourAction() 
        {
            $this->loadLayout();    
            $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setRobots('NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW');
            $this->renderLayout(); 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is for a category or product, you can add this to `custom layout` section:

```
<reference name="head">
     <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW</value></action>
</reference>
```

Or for a single page add this to your `local.xml`, example for contacts page

```
<contacts_index_index>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW</value></action>
    </reference>
</contacts_index_index>
```